# posgres sql : how to select in list of value

Tags: postgresql

posgres sql

i have table like this

table: user

| user_id | user_name |
| --- | --- |
| u1 | user1 |
| u2 | user2 |
| u3 | user3 |
| u4 | user4 |

table : visit

| visit_id | user_id | visit_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| v1 | u1 | 2023-01-15 |
| v2 | u1 | 2023-01-16 |
| v3 | u2 | 2023-01-17 |
| v4 | u2 | 2023-01-18 |
| v5 | u4 | 2023-01-19 |
| v6 | u4 | 2023-01-20 |
| v7 | u4 | 2023-01-21 |
| v8 | u4 | 2023-01-22 |
| v9 | u4 | 2023-01-23 |
| v10 | u4 | 2023-01-24 |
| v11 | u4 | 2023-01-25 |

How can i fillter list of value like this :

after join tale

and i want to :: where user_name in ('user1','user2','user4')  and  user1 = '2023-01-16' , user2 = '2023-01-17' , user4 = '2023-01-23'

Result

| User id | visit_date |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | 2023-01-16 |
| user2 | 2023-01-17 |
| user4 | 2023-01-23 |

Comment: You mean you want each of the users only on their corresponding, own, specific date, rather than any of these users on any of these dates? `select a.user_name, b.visit_date from user a inner join visit b on a.user_id=b.user_id where (a.user_name,b.visit_date) in (('user1','2023-01-16'),('user2','2023-01-17'),('user4','2023-01-23'));`

Comment: your solution is the way that i need . thank you very much.

Comment: I've re-posted it as a proper answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want each of the users only on their corresponding, own, specific date, rather than any of these users on any of these dates:

```sql
select a.user_name, 
       b.visit_date 
from user a 
   inner join visit b 
      using(user_id) 
where (a.user_name, b.visit_date) 
      in (('user1', '2023-01-16'),
          ('user2', '2023-01-17'),
          ('user4', '2023-01-23'));
```

As long as those are not hand-picked user+date pairs, there might be an easier way to specify which pairs to return using [Date/Time functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html), [conditional expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html) and [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) - they let you formulate very specific rules like 'for each user, return only their second date and not if it's on a Thursday or the Weekend, and skip leap years'.